# Should Open Seal open electronic locks?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-20th-anniversary

The gift Open Seal states that

> The werewolf can open nearly any sort of closed or locked physical
>   device. A raccoon-spirit teaches this Gift.

RaW it seems to me that there is nothing explicitly impeding the use of the gift to open an electronic lock with a number pad for example, but at the same time it feels (to me at least) that the spirit of the rule is that it shouldn't be possible, maybe interpreting that physical =/= digital (but then again the lock itself is physical). As in W20 it does not require a gnosis expenditure it seems to overpower for a 1st rank gift.

I would prefer an official answer and if there is none a reasonable explanation in either direction.

Comment: @Mindwin Werewolf 20th anniversary, I have removed the other tag.

Comment: Regarding your remark that it is too powerful to be a 1st level gift, there are very few doors with an electronic lock that cannot be broken by a raging ahroun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Took me some time to reach the gaming store to browse the book, but here you go...

> System: The player rolls Gnosis (difficulty of the local Gauntlet rating).

Since places where an electronic lock would exist are way deep in the Weaver's domain, the gauntlet rating should be at least 8.

But **yes** it should be able to open, with some luck.

This is assuming there is no supernatural effect strengthening the lock.